# Using `const` breaks program

Tags: c, opengl, constants

I wrote a small test program using SDL 2.0 and OpenGL 1.1, and ran into this very strange problem: Making certain variables `const` breaks the program! Can anyone explain why this happens?

### Code

```
static float vertexes[] = { // Good
static uint8_t colors[] = {

static float vertexes[] = { // No problem
static const uint8_t colors[] = {

static const float vertexes[] = { // Bad
static const uint8_t colors[] = {

static const float vertexes[] = { // VERY bad
static uint8_t colors[] = {
```

### Respective Screenshots

[image: Screen when neither are constant]
[image: Screen when <code>colors</code> is constant]
[image: Screen when <code>vertexes</code> is constant]
[image: Screen when both are constant]

### Full (working) program

This program gives the desired behaviour. Comment out the `const`s to view the broken versions.

```
// gcc -o main main.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -I. -lm -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -mwindows
#include <SDL.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr))

typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} vec3;

bool running;
int width, height;
SDL_Window *window;
SDL_GLContext ctx;
vec3 rotation;

static /* const */ float vertexes[] = {
     1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

     1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,

     1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,

     1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

     1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
};
static /* const */ uint8_t colors[] = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0xFF,
    0x00, 0x00, 0xFF,
    0x00, 0x00, 0xFF,
    0x00, 0x00, 0xFF,
    0x00, 0x00, 0xFF,
    0x00, 0x00, 0xFF,

    0x00, 0x7F, 0x3F,
    0x00, 0x7F, 0x3F,
    0x00, 0x7F, 0x3F,
    0x00, 0x7F, 0x3F,
    0x00, 0x7F, 0x3F,
    0x00, 0x7F, 0x3F,

    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,

    0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00,

    0xFF, 0xB3, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0xB3, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0xB3, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0xB3, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0xB3, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0xB3, 0x00,

    0xFF, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0x00, 0x00,
};

void onresize(void)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60, (float)width/(float)height, 1, -1);
}

void init(void);
void fini(void);

void loop(void);

void handle(void);
void render(void);
void update(void);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    init();
    loop();
    fini();

    return 0;
}

void init(void)
{
    SDL_DisplayMode mode;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)) return;

    SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode(0, &mode);
    width = mode.w;
    height = mode.h;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Game",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        width,
        height,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN
    );
    if (!window) return;
    ctx = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    if (!ctx) return;

    onresize();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    running = true;
}
void fini(void)
{
    if (ctx) SDL_GL_DeleteContext(ctx);
    if (window) SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    SDL_Quit();
}

void loop(void)
{
    while (running) {
        handle();
        render();
        update();
    }
}

void handle(void)
{
    SDL_Event event;

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
            switch (event.window.event) {
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED:
                width = event.window.data1, height = event.window.data2;
                onresize();

                break;
            }
            break;
        case SDL_QUIT:
            running = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
void render(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.9f, 0.8f, 0.7f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 0, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(rotation.x, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(rotation.y, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(rotation.z, 0, 0, 1);
    glScalef(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f);

    glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(9.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 9.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 9.0f);
    glEnd();

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexes);
        glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, colors);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, ARRAYSIZE(vertexes));

    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
}
void update(void)
{
    rotation.x++;
    rotation.y++;
}
```

Alternatively available [here](http://pastebin.com/ZMT6hgzU).

Comment: The code relevant to the problem belongs in the question itself.  Preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Additionally, we don't know what "breaks the program" means in this case, and the screenshots are useless because we don't know what the program is supposed to do.  In any event, if the problem is incorrect output, as opposed to the program crashing, then I find it highly doubtful that the problem revolves around `const`-qualification.

Comment: @JohnBollinger StackOverflow did not allow me to post the code, it kept complaining about the code being outside of code markup (it wasn't), until I removed it (It did work this time). I added the word "respective" before "screenshots" for those who did not figure out that the screenshots are in the same order as the code snippets above them. I don't think it involves around const qualification either, but the program _DOES_ misbehave when I add the `const` keyword. It could be a problem with Windows, OpenGL, GCC, I don't know. That is my question.

Comment: Why are you using `ARRAYSIZE(vertexes)` instead of `ARRAYSIZE(vertexes) / 3` in your `glDrawArrays()` call?  `count` is the number of vertices, not the number of `float`s.  Right now you're telling OpenGL to read off the end of the `vertexes`/`colors` arrays into `$DIETY`-knows-what.  You're lucky it isn't segfaulting.

Comment: @genpfault Thank you, I think I understand the problem now. I am pretty new to OpenGL, and therefore didn't know what 'indices' ment.

Comment: @genpfault: Question is reopened. You should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ARRAYSIZE(vertexes) / 3` instead of `ARRAYSIZE(vertexes)` in your `glDrawArrays()` call.

`glDrawArrays()`'s `count` argument is the number of vertices, not the number of floats.  Right now you're telling OpenGL to read off the end of the vertexes/colors arrays into `$DIETY`-knows-what. You're lucky it isn't segfaulting.

`const`/non-`const` is probably just [switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) which [segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) the arrays are ending up in, providing different "garbage" vertices for OpenGL to try to interpret.